# Adding minutes to current time

Tags: java

how do i  add x amount of minutes to the current time?

as i currently have

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
        return ((int) ((x) +      ));
```

which gets my time in HH:mm format, but what i want it to return is x minutes + current time, how would i return this ?

Comment: It's time for... JodaTime!!! Ho-ho-hooo!

Answer (score 4):

If you have `Calendar` instance it is easy:

```
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTES, x);
```

Comment: It should be called Calendar.MINUTE (singular)

Answer (score 1):

Just add the amount of time to cal before formatting it.

```
void    add(int field, int amount)
```

Adds or subtracts the specified amount of time to the given calendar field, based on the calendar's rules.

Field would be Calendar.MINUTE for example

Answer (score 1):

Add this line before `System.out.println`

```
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, x);
```

Answer (score 1):

Joda [DateTime library](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) provide a lot of common and usefull date/time manipulation methods. It is worth to look. In your case you can simply write:

```
DateTime addTwoMinutes = DateTime.now().plusMinutes(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
return now + (minutes * 60 * 1000);
```